# Rails gems that have assets are not added to config.assets.paths

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I am upgrading a Rails 3.0 application to Rails 4.2. Upon adding the asset pipeline in Rails 3.1, I noticed that gems that contain assets are not added to `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

I added these gems to my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I would expect that to add these directories to `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

```
 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/images
 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts
 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/stylesheets
 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
```

However, it only shows the folders in my `app/assets` folder. Here is the complete output of `Rails.application.config.assets`. I have the exact same configuration in other Rails applications where I am not experiencing this problem.

```
 {:_blocks=>
   [#<Proc:0x007fa6070a9b50@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:126>,
    #<Proc:0x007fa6070a9948@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:130>,
    #<Proc:0x007fa6070a9600@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:137>,
    #<Proc:0x007fa6070a8fc0@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:149>,
    #<Proc:0x007fa6070a8958@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:153>,
    #<Proc:0x007fa6070a87f0@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:157>],
  :paths=>
   ["~/my-app/app/assets/images",
    "~/my-app/app/assets/javascripts",
    "~/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets"],
  :precompile=>
   [#<Proc:0x007fa6070ab680@~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:84 (lambda)>,
    /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/],
  :prefix=>"/assets",
  :manifest=>nil,
  :quiet=>false,
  :version=>"1.0",
  :debug=>true,
  :compile=>true,
  :digest=>true,
  :cache_limit=>52428800,
  :gzip=>true,
  :check_precompiled_asset=>true,
  :compress=>false,
  :raise_runtime_errors=>true,
  :enabled=>true,
  :logger=>false,
  :resolve_with=>[:environment]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite likely you still have the `assets` group in the `Gemfile`.

The `assets` grouping concept is a relic from Rails 3, and [has been removed in rails 4.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile)

> Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile. You'd need to remove
>   that line from your Gemfile when upgrading.

On a rails app that I upgraded recently from 3.0 to 4.0, including the gems in `assets` group prevented the gem assets from being included in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`. Removing the `assets` group from the Gemfile, and updating the bundle fixed the problem.